# Type safe activator hanging on Compiling project definition

Tags: scala, typesafe-activator

recently i updated the activator, and i can not create any project from template. All my old projects still works fine, and can be opened, but i can't do anything new from the UI.

Is it a known issue ?

Comment: any solution now?

Comment: facing the same issue.